# Why does my code continue?

Tags: python, for-loop, return

this code is supposed to take a user input for the type of shape. then take an input of the height then print a shape made of *'s (triangle/square for now)

the code works until the user types in a bad input to start, then a correct function name and tries to close it. any ideas how to fix it?

error:

```
Enter shape to draw (q to quit): sad
Unknown shape. Please try again
Enter shape to draw (q to quit): triangle
Enter size: 6
*
**
***
****
*****
******
Enter shape to draw (q to quit): q
Goodbye
Enter size: #this should not be there
```

the whole code is 
    """ shape programme by jordan hampson"""

```
def main():
    """main boss function"""
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()

    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        return



    else:
        get_valid_shape(shape)

        call_shape(shape)

        main()



def call_shape(shape):
    """CALLS THE shape"""

    size = int(input("Enter size: "))
    get_valid_size(size)
    if shape == "square":
        return print_square(size)

    elif shape == "triangle":
        return print_triangle(size)

    else: 
        return main()


def get_valid_size(size):
    """checks to see if the size is valid"""
    if size <= 0:
        print("Value must be at least 1")
        main()

def get_valid_shape(shape):
    """gets a valid shape"""
    shape_1 = shape
    shapes = ["square", "triangle", "q"]
    while shape_1 not in shapes:
        print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
        return main()


def print_square(size):
    """prints a square from the input"""
    for _ in range(0, size):
        print(size * "*")


def print_triangle(size): 
    """prints a triangle in *'s"""   
    for _ in range(1, size +1):
        print((size -(size -_)) * "*")  

main()
```

Comment: why do you call `main`? please don't. perhaps you want to search for some examples that show you how to do error handling properly?

Comment: These returns make it unreadable... use `raise SystemExit` to terimate your script right after you're printing GoodBye

Comment: tried raise SystemExit 
this happened...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 16, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 51, in get_valid_shape
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 20, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in main
builtins.SystemExit:

Comment: actually `SystemExit` won't bring up any error, maybe that's because of your IDE? try to run your standalone code outside of the IDE using CMD terminal

Comment: @PYPL this has to be submitted through a pylint checker, will this be ok?

Comment: In your place I would really try to write the program without calling main() anywhere except once at the end in order to get the whole thing going. It seems to me it would really hard to get rid of all issues the way the program is currently written.

Comment: can't really tell, I would rewrite the code without using `main()` to be sure it does not require `SystemExit`

Answer (score 1):

It's due to your fonction get_valid_shape(), the fonction call the fonction main() so when you enter "sad" you start a new main() but in the fonction get_valid_shape() (on the main process your are still at the line `get_valid_shape(shape)`). When you press "q" you quit this line and pass to `call_shape(shape)` the prevous shape was a triangle so it ask you to input a size.

To avoid this I suggest this code

```
def main():
    shape = ""
    while shape != "q":
        """main boss function"""
        shape = "" #reinitialize 
        shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()

        if shape == "q":
            print("Goodbye")

        elif get_valid_shape(shape) :
            call_shape(shape)

        else:
            print("Unknown shape. Please try again")



def call_shape(shape):
    """CALLS THE shape"""

    size = int(input("Enter size: "))#ask a 1st time withour print error message
    while get_valid_size(size): #while size is false, ask again
        size = int(input("Enter size: "))

    if shape == "square":
        return print_square(size)

    elif shape == "triangle":
        return print_triangle(size)



def get_valid_size(size):
    """checks to see if the size is valid"""
    if size <= 0: 
        print("Value must be at least 1")
        return True #return true to loop at the while
    else :
        return False #return false to break the while

def get_valid_shape(shape):
    """gets a valid shape"""
    shape_1 = shape
    shapes = ["square", "triangle", "q"]
    if shape_1 not in shapes:
        return False
    else :
        return True


def print_square(size):
    """prints a square from the input"""
    for _ in range(0, size):
        print(size * "*")


def print_triangle(size): 
    """prints a triangle in *'s"""   
    for _ in range(1, size +1):
        print((size -(size -_)) * "*")  

main()
```

I suggest you the module pdb in python. It's a debug module very useful (you can see how run your algorithme step by step, go to somewhere, into a function etc ...) [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have used these `return`'s in a wrong way, you don't really need any return'ed value since you're doing NOTHING with them in your code!

```
def main():
    """main boss function"""
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()

    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")

    else:
        get_valid_shape(shape)
        call_shape(shape)
        main()

def call_shape(shape):
    """CALLS THE shape"""

    size = int(input("Enter size: "))
    get_valid_size(size)
    if shape == "square":
        print_square(size)

    elif shape == "triangle":
        print_triangle(size)

    else: 
        main()

def get_valid_size(size):
    """checks to see if the size is valid"""
    if size <= 0:
        print("Value must be at least 1")
        main()

def get_valid_shape(shape):
    """gets a valid shape"""
    while shape not in ["square", "triangle", "q"]:
        print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
        main()


def print_square(size):
    """prints a square from the input"""
    for _ in range(0, size):
        print(size * "*")


def print_triangle(size): 
    """prints a triangle in *'s"""   
    for _ in range(1, size +1):
        print((size -(size -_)) * "*")  

main()
```

In my opinion this is an awful code since you have used useless functions, when you could write your whole code without them.

```
inProgram = True
while inProgram:
    shape = raw_input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    while shape not in ["square", "triangle", "q"]:
        shape = raw_input("Unknown shape. Please try again: ").lower()
    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        inProgram=False
    else:
        size = raw_input("Enter size: ")
        while not size.isdigit() or size<=0:
            size = raw_input("Value must be at least 1\nTry again: ")
        size = int(size)
        if shape == "square":
            for _ in range(0, size):
                print(size * "*")
        else:
            for _ in range(1, size +1):
                print((size -(size -_)) * "*")
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add, this was for an assignment. one of the criteria was that no function could be longer than 12 lines. hence the multiple functions